# Get data from href but it is not usable

Tags: python, html, unicode, encode, webapp2

Recently i started working on a project. In which i am sending data from a html page using `<a>` tag. At backend i am using python webapp2 feamework. When i get the data it show perfectly. But when i compare it with some string for further usage it does not work.

I know when we get data it is in unicode. But i converted it to utf-8 and it is still not working.

Here is the code in html. Suppose i sent `"item 2" as itemname`

```
<a href="/main/items/?itemname= {{res.itemName}}&itemdescription={{res.itemDescription}}"> Click me </a>
```

The code which i am using to fetch data is

```
def get(self,nam,des):

   nam = self.request.get('itemname')
   itemDesc= self.request.get('itemdescription')
   name = nam.encode('utf-8')

   if name == "item 2":
       self.response.write("Equal")
```

I also try it without encoding but still it not works. It Show the value of item name perfectly. But it is not comparing them. Please help where i am doing mistake.

Comment: What happens when you print the variable?  And what version of python are you using?

Comment: I am using python 2.7. It prints the value which is sent from the html page perfectly.

Comment: Perhaps you need to `import urllib` and `urllib.unquote(name)` as well

Comment: Do i also need to something in my <a> tag from where i am sending the data.

Comment: Also, there is a space at the beginning `?itemname={{res.itemName}}...`

Comment: I wouldn't think so.  As long as the page renders correctly, that side is probably good.  I'd be more suspicious that URI hitting your code at all, and whether it's pull out the correct values.  `nam` should at least resemble `item 2` if you're using the framework correctly

Comment: The code does work ` name =urllib.unquote(nam)`

       ` if name == " item 2":`
           ` self.response.write("Equal")``

Comment: But i have to give a empty space in start of  " item 2". This is due to which reason?

Comment: Your response will be appreciated @Charles L.

Comment: Thank you so much :). I figured out my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like 2 issues, there is a space before the expected value is set, and the string is urlquoted.

To fix the space:

```
<a href="/main/items/?itemname={{res.itemName}}&itemdescription={{res.itemDescription}}"> Click me </a>
```

And then to work with the encoding, add `import urllib` and change the line

```
name = nam.encode('utf-8')
```

to

```
name = urllib.unquote(nam.encode('utf-8'))
```